# Form gets stuck/freezes when windows event happens

Tags: vb.net, windows

I took over a GUI which has the purpose to communicate on USB (via a PEAK USB/CAN device) with an Electronic Control Unit. The problem is that, **sometimes**, when some Windows events take place (take the PC out of the docking station/ take the monitor out of the laptop, sometimes when plugging in a USB mem stick), my GUI (MainForm) gets stuck/ freezes in the background without any possibility to access it with the mouse, keyboard or from the Task Manger (only close it but not bring to front) but it is still working and updating values received from the PEAK system via USB.

Can you help me with this issue, please? Take into account that this project was not started by me I just took over in order to update it's features when the guy left. Can this issue appear due to the PCAN drivers? Can I find a work around?

Comment: Without seeing your code how do you expect us to help? Please edit your question and include it according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code is pretty large. Taking into account that this issue happens when the GUI is working, what part of the code would you like me to share? The USB configuration? Com ports configuration? Timers? I thought there was a problem related to windows events that need to be handled inside the code...

Comment: I have no idea where the problem could be nor what to look for. I haven't worked with USB nor Com in VB, but even someone who has will need some code to work with. -- Best is if you could use [**a debugger**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx) and try narrowing down the problem. When an app is freezing there is something occupying the UI thread and stopping it from redrawing. A long-running operation in a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is one example.

Comment: Like [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) states: restarting from scratch and/or removing parts of code are a good ways of narrowing down the problem.